# No gyms or pokestops on my map

Tags: pokemon-go

I have reached level 5, but all of a sudden I don't seem to see any pokestops or gyms or pokemons its like just the map is there and nothing else no matter which place I go.

Comment: Yes I have waited patiently and also restarted my phone multiple times vut still the same issue please advice

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by taking time to load the map, usually because either your internet connection or the servers are having issues.

Wait a few minutes. If that doesn't work, restart your phone.